# Changing the file descriptor size in httperf

Tags: benchmarking, ubuntu-12.04, httperf

I'm doing a series of benchmarks and found the [httpperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/) tool.

But the version in my ubuntu 12.04 has a too small file descriptor size. Because it warns me with this message:

> - httperf: warning: open file limit > FD_SETSIZE; limiting max. # of open files to FD_SETSIZE

There used to be guide to compile httperf with a bigger size in http://gom-jabbar.org/articles/2009/02/04/httperf-and-file-descriptors but the site is down now.

Does anyone knows the steps to compile the tool with the proper settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've always followed the instructions [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~brecht/servers/openfiles.html), which should set the global values properly. You can check by issuing a `ulimit -n` (N.B. I had to include `ulimit -n 65535` in my .profile — for some reason named users don't require this but root does.)

Don't forget to recompile httperf. Before doing `make install` issue a `./httperf -v | grep maximum` — you should see 65535. If not, something went wrong.

I am working on a similar project (httperf 0.9.0 on Ubuntu 12.04) but I am having some difficulty getting httperf to actually compile properly. I'm sure I've forgotten something basic, but let me know how you fare. EDIT: Realized my problem was a library version incompatibility. I imported the binary built on a different server and it works fine.