# Increase httperf file descriptor size

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, httperf

I'm trying to use httperf to make some tests on a server application that I made.

I installed httperf via apt-get:

> sudo apt-get install httperf

When I run any sample, httperf returns a warning like this:

> httperf: warning: open file limit > FD_SETSIZE; limiting max. # of open files to FD_SETSIZE

I read that I have to change "__FD_SETSIZE" in "typesizes.h" but it´s not working though (event when I change it to "65532"):

> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/typesizes.h

Does anyone know the steps to recompile increasing file descriptor size? I receive limit error when I use rate > 40, for example:

> httperf --client=0/1 --server=127.0.0.1 --port=8080 --uri=/index.html --send-buffer=4096 --recv-buffer=16384 --num-conns=5000 --num-calls=1 --rate=40

Thank you very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16445074/992406  or https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/benchmark/httperf/

Comment: The second link was really helpful.. thanks @houssam